# Rotate texture only on part of an object

Tags: texturing, objects

I am looking for help rotating a texture on part of a chair. The back of the chair displays properly while the front of the chair displays the texture upsidedown (rotated 180 deg.). I am able to rotate using the nodes in the shader editor but this will rotate all sides of the chair and then I have the same issue.

Any help would be appreciated. I am very new to Blender so please bear with me.

Thank you.

Comment: Hi and welcome :) Please [edit] your question and add an image of your material/ texture setup. Probably simplest is to edit UV in that area, but more information would be helpful.

Comment: Enter your UV editing tab. Select the offending face on the UV map, then rotate it by 180 degrees (R +180).

Comment: Thank you. I ended up creating a copy of the chair and removing the back from one object and the inverse on the other and now I have control over each portion independent from one another. This may not be best practice but I tried editing the UV map using R180 and it distorted that area. It looked like it was anchored onto something so it did not rotate as intended.